# How do we differentiate between $\log_{10}A$, $\log A$, and $\ln A$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, logarithms

How do we differentiate $\log_{10}A$,  $\log A$, $\ln A$?  I  always thought $\log A= \log_{10}A$, but got stuck in understanding one of the logarithm problems at this site recently. Now, I am aware that quite some folks  interpret $\log A = \ln A$. Just wondering how the majority of us  use and differentiate these logarithm notations to avoid confusions?

Comment: For mathematicians, there _is_ only one kind of logarithm (since all other bases can be converted), and that is the "natural logarithm":  so they write "log x", while almost everyone else writes "ln x".  For almost everyone else, base 10 is the kind that is used, so they call _that_ "log x".  As to your question, though, you will see both notations on this site; it will usually be clear from context that they are (almost) all using natural logarithms.

Comment: This makes sense :-), since most schools do not expect their students to be mathematicians, so they teach us $\log x$ means base 10.

Comment: You can also think like this - $\ln x =\log_e x$ and when no base is mentioned generally base $e$  is considered in mathematics.

Comment: If you venture across disciplines, you will find that mathematical and other notations have "local dialects", so you have to get used to the variants when you read papers or otherwise communicate with other practitioners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log A$ can mean either $\log_{10} A$ or $\ln A = \log_e A$ depending an what book you are using.

Doesn't matter.

$\ln_e x = \log_e x$ is the "natural base" with the natural property that $\frac {de^x}{dx} = e^x$.  And any *other* base can be derived as $b^x = e^{x \ln b}$.

Now we can use the chain rule that $\frac {d b^x}{dx} = \frac {de^{x\ln b}}{dx} = \frac{d e^{x\ln b}}{d x\ln b} \cdot \frac {dx\ln b}{dx} = e^{x\ln b}\ln b= b^x \ln b$.

So $\frac {d10^x}{dx} = 10^x \ln 10$.

We can use the chain rule to calculat that $x = e^{\ln x}$ so $\frac {dx}{dx} = \frac {de^{\ln x}}{dx} = \frac {de^{\ln x}}{d\ln x}\cdot \frac {d\ln x} {dx}=e^{\ln x} \frac {d\ln x}{dx} = x \frac {d\ln x}{dx}$.

But $\frac {dx}{dx} = 1$ so $\frac {d\ln x}{dx} = \frac 1x$.

$x = b^{\log_b x}$ so $\frac {dx}{dx} = \frac {db^{\log_b x}}{d\log_b x} \cdot \frac {d\log_b x}{dx}$.

So

$1 = \ln b \cdot b^{\log_b x} \cdot \frac {d\log_b x}{dx}$ and

$1 = x\ln b\cdot \frac {d\log_b x}{dx}$ and

$\frac {d\log_b x}{dx} = \frac 1{x\ln b}$

And $\frac {d\log_{10} x}{dx} = \frac 1{x\ln 10}$.

....

That's actually a little backwards as we actually usually *define* $\ln x = \int_1^x \frac 1t dt$ first and work all the rest out backwards.

Answer (score 4):

There are three special cases of the base $b$ that have names/notations (and where they are most often found):

- Common logarithm: $\log_{10} x = \log x$ (engineering, seismology, acoustics)
- Natural logarithm: $\log_e x = \ln x$ (mathematics)
- Binary logarithm: $\log_2 x = \lg x$ (computer science)

Of course because of the *change-of-base formula,* every logarithm is just a scaled version of every other logarithm:
$$
\log_b x = \frac{\log_c x}{\log_c b} 
$$

For example, $\ln x \approx 2.303 \log x$ and $\log x \approx 0.434 \ln x$, and those coefficients are reciprocals.

**An issue/ambiguity** In many uses of logarithms in higher mathematics, such as when looking at asymptotics of certain sequences or functions, the distinction of this multiple is immaterial, so people just write $\log x$ (and usually mean the *natural* logarithm), but you probably won't encounter this notation in undergraduate mathematics.

Of course, if the distinction of the base is important, you can always just explicitly state what your notation means. The notation works for you, not the other way around!

Comment: A very nice answer, with one small caveat:  in mathematics, $\log$ more often than not denotes the natural logarithm, rather than the common logarithm.  Hence, in the bulleted list, it would be reasonable to write the second item as "$\log_\mathrm{e}(x) = \ln(x) = \log(x)$ (mathematics)".

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use $\log A = \log_{10}A$ when referring to something in science or engineering. This is because a lot of things in science (scientific notation, pH scale, etc.) tend to use base 10.

Whenever talking about mathematics I use $\log A = \ln A$. This is how I see it done in most math except high school.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it depends. From my experience, $\log A=\log_{10} A$. For most fields, this is what the notation means. **HOWEVER**, in mathematics, $e$ has so many good properties that we define $\log A=\ln A$. That's also why $\ln$ is called the natural log. It's the natural log, the interpreted log. A simple way to remember is *What feels natural? The natural log!*